# Im not getting push notifications iOS Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am not getting push notifications coming through onto my device. I have all my certificates in place and i do get test pushes coming through. my code to send push works fine i can see that on parse. it also says pushes sent but no pushes come through to device due to code below.

My code below in appdelegate didFinishLaunching method gives the alert to allow push notes but none come through

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    } else {
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
       [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
```

If i move this line `[application registerForRemoteNotifications]` anywhere else my app crashes. this line is the only issue if i move it anywhere and i have tried it every where it causes crash (app does not open at all).

help me fix crash and get push notifications coming through?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this one:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
   {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   }
else
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
  }
```

make sure that you have remote notification on in background mode capabilities and have uploaded .p12 without any password in parse.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks still no luck I have also checked parse everything looks ok there. Why is that line causing a issue?

Comment: The only line that cause the crash for me is [application registerForRemoteNotifications]

Comment: are you checking on iOS7 or iOS8? and which Xcode version ?

Comment: I'm running ios9 and I have the latest version of Xcode running ios9

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a PFInstallation to your device. From Parse's iOS guide, under "Push Notifications" -

> Every Parse application installed on a device registered for push notifications has an associated PFInstallation object. The PFInstallation object is where you store all the data needed to target push notifications

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
  [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
  [currentInstallation saveInBackground]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using currently in my own iOS app using Parse as a BaaS. Your code fails to implement a `PFInstallation` which is stored in a Parse table.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.addUniqueObject("ExampleChannel", forKey: "channels")
    installation.saveInBackground()
}
```

Hope I was able to help you out, best of luck.